# Django auth custom business logic - how do I raise custom error message?

Tags: python, django, authentication

So I'm using django.contrib.auth module.
My business logic is: a user has a **status** field, that's either PENDING, ACTIVE, or DISABLED (the **is_active** field is not enough to suit my needs).

I overwrote the auth backend like so:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from app import constants

class ModelBackend(object):
  """
  Authenticates against settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL.
  """

  def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
    UserModel = get_user_model()
    if username is None:
      username = kwargs.get(UserModel.USERNAME_FIELD)
    try:
      user = UserModel._default_manager.get_by_natural_key(username)

      if not user.status == constants.ACCOUNT_STATUS['ACTIVE']:
        return None # This is where I prevent pending users to log in.

      if user.check_password(password):
        return user
    except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
      # Run the default password hasher once to reduce the timing
      # difference between an existing and a non-existing user (#20760).
      UserModel().set_password(password)
```

At the moment, I'm able to prevent pending users to log in, but I can't find a way to display a custom error message. The error currently says:

> Unable to login with provided credentials.

Also, this may not be related to my problem but might be useful: I am using Django Rest Framework with JWT. So I'm not using a Django Form, all is performed via ajax calls, and the response to a sign-in request is rendered as json in the following format:

```
{
    "non_field_errors": [
        "Unable to login with provided credentials."
    ]
}
```

So i'd like to "inject" my custom error message into "non_field_errors". Something like: "Please activate your account before logging in".

Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using this package for jwt http://getblimp.github.io/django-rest-framework-jwt/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dig into django-rest-framework-jwt you can find that "Unable to login with ..." is set in JSONWebTokenSerializer (https://github.com/GetBlimp/django-rest-framework-jwt/blob/f07772769c0f72f971daefe1d9426a90ea099a63/rest_framework_jwt/serializers.py#L66). Since this message is hard-coded you can't simply inject your own message.

To override it you will need to:

1. Create your own serializer based on JSONWebTokenSerializer and
   override it's validate method recording to your needs (changing
   error message for example)
2. Create custom api view based on default ObtainJSONWebToken view (https://github.com/GetBlimp/django-rest-framework-jwt/blob/f07772769c0f72f971daefe1d9426a90ea099a63/rest_framework_jwt/views.py#L69) and change serializer_class attribute to your custom webtoken serializer.
3. Use your custom api view in urls.py instead of the default one.